# How can I decode a token in Node.js? jwt.verify() fails

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to decode a token using jwt in nodejs. This is not working, each time I get `undefined` as the decoded token.

Here is my code:

```
const token  = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET');
const userId = decodedToken.userId;

console.log(decodedToken);
console.log(decodedToken.userId);
```

Below are screenshots of postman and response I get when I do `console.log`[image]

[image]

Comment: can you check that token always has a value?

Comment: I have checked it several time . If I `console.log()` the token itself, i get a value but decoding is the issue.

Comment: and what's the output of `console.log(token)`? In many cases when people ask why their code is not working it's in fact simply an expired or invalid token. Maybe you just get undefined in the last line, because it doesn't contain `userId`.

Comment: Are you using Bearer token ?

Comment: Yes , I am using bearer token

Comment: It looks like you don't have any payload data in token. Can you share more code as in where you are generating token as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. The time I was encoding/generating the token , I did not provide the property `userId` with a value. That is the reason it was declaring it undefined.

I had to make some changes and it works just fine.

```
           const token = jwt.sign(
              {userId: user.userid},
              'RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET',
              {expiresIn: '24h'});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know what's in the token, you have to do it like this, it's an option:

first:

```
nmp i jwt-decode
```

Second:

```
import jwt_decode  from 'jwt-decode';  // For ES6
const jwt_decoder = require('jwt-decode'); // For classic node.js

var token = "cnueownvwnqc..." // This is your token, you can send it from the frontend 

var decoded = jwt_decode(token); // Decoding
console.log(decode.userId); // Dictionary array
```

Comment: *don't do it with jwt.verify, because this function is not a decoder, it is just a signature validator.* - this is not correct! In case of the [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) package which the OP seems to use, `verify` returns the decoded payload if the signature is valid. `decode` just decodes, without verification.

Comment: Well, in that case it can be done in both ways, I comment on the answer that it worked for me to extract the data without having to use the signature, which in my implementation was more optimal.

Comment: it's ok that `decode` is better for your use-case, but in your answer you make a false claim about `verify`. I suggest to edit this to something like "instead of `verify` you can also use `decode`, if you don't verification...'  After all it's not even an answer to the OPs question, their problem was just that a certain property could no be found in th payload.

Comment: Well, i changed the answer ¿It's better?